# Black screen at the start of Ubuntu on VMware

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Ubuntu on VMware on Windows 10. 
After installation, black cmd appears and I can't get rid of it. 
Not either by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> nor by any other means. 
How should I proceed?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about your first image as being the "black screen"? 
That looks like a login screen. 
Type the username you defined during the installation process
and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I logged in yet I remain in the same black cmd environment. I want to have desktop environment where there should be icons as Ubuntu normally has. Note that I have installed Ubuntu Server. Thanks